# Make animation during mouseover and out different element

Tags: javascript, animation

I have an un-ordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

And I will add the class `.active` to the item with mouseovered, this is the effect:

[image]

However I wonder if I can make some animation during the active item changed?

For example, make the `black ground` move from one item to another?

Comment: I think the hardest part with your design is that the foreground colour of the text needs to change when the dark background is underneath it. To do it smoothly, you would need to somehow change the colour of the text in front of the background as it moves, which would be very tricky indeed. It might look better if you can come up with a colour scheme where you don't need to change the colour of the text.

Comment: Of course you can, you can animate anything you want, just go for it!

Comment: If ground "moving" is not must-have, you could purely use css3 `transition` to make animation on `background-color` and `color`. And you don't need javascript for adding `active` class, just use `:hover` in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **CSS3 transition** like:
**[jsFiddle demo with background color fade](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/76eneymj/)**
**[jsFiddle demo with background image animation](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/76eneymj/1/)**

```
li, li *{              /* Target LI and it's children */
   backgorund:#fff;
   transition: 0.3s;
}
li:hover{
   background: 2C3E50; /* will be applied smoothly */
   color: #fff;        /* will be applied smoothly */
}
li:hover h2{
   color: #fff;        /* will be applied smoothly */
}
```

So yes, you *don't* need JS,
 you don't need any special class,
 simply CSS's `:hover` selector.